# How to get the contents of a *user-selected* *local* file in javascript without any posts, gets, submits, etc

Tags: javascript, file, local

I'm using jQuery if that's any benefit; and I would like to have:

1. The user selects a file on the **local filesystem**
2. my javascript gets the contents of said file without going "across the wire".
3. I am checking the browser type and am prepared to use completely different 
   code for each browser.  IE and FF are the two that I am currently writing for.
4. I am Not using php, just straight javascript on a form.
5. I do not want any gets, posts, submits, ajax, or any other network activity until the contents of the file have been acquired, validated, and manipulated (all of which my script will do; this question is just for getting the guts of the file).
6. I do not necessarily need to get the path.  I don't particularly **want** to get the path.  The generally accepted notion of "secure" having the user pick the file and my script just gets the contents.  That's fine, but if I get the path I won't complain.

I've googled this a lot and haven't gotten any solution that simply works.

---

I've looked at [Mozilla XPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I//O#User_input_via_nsIFilePicker), but the file picker nsIFilePicker requires privilege escalation, which I just don't want to deal with.

---

I've tried using a regular

```
<input type="file" onclick="fileCheck(this); return false" . . . />

with

function fileCheck ()
{
  var path = obj.files[0].mozFullPath;
}
```

But even though you can see mozFullPath in Firebug, it does not show up for Javascript (ostensibly for security reasons).

Any ideas?

Comment: I found it interesting you can get a preview/data merely by selecting a png. Not sure if this is of relevence, but it is interesting: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Answer (score 8):

You can; have a look at [HTML5 Rocks - Reading local files in JavaScript](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

Comment: Nice reply.  I read on this before, but the web pages I saw said that the file API in HTML 5 was not implemented on FF yet.  Maybe they were wrong; I'll try it.

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the link in your answer as links could rot.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, for blindingly obvious security reasons.

Comment: Wish I could click +1 more than once sometimes.

Comment: I wouldn't say they were blindingly obvious. It's hardly any less secure than a user selecting a file and having a dangerous 'upload' button that sends the contents to the server. The security part is bypassed by the user actively choosing the file. They are saying here it is, do with it as you will.

Comment: no they're blindingly obvious.  What if I just happen to select my tax return by mistake first? I surely don't want to send that.  If you could read any file merely SELECTED, that would lead to a lot of security issues.  The action of having to actually submit the form helps provide a quick gutcheck.  That being said, if you've got a user who just doesn't know better...

Comment: So what if he asked, "How can I [upload a file] on my users local machine, I've gotten to the point where the user has selected the file" - would that be a 'blindingly obvious' security hole? A quick google has revealed a few hits showing how to have a file uploader that does not require the button to be pressed.

Comment: It's blindingly obvious because if the OS & browser allows Javascript to access local files by _any_ means, even if it's programmed to require a file selection first, security flaws in that process could be catastrophic. The failsafe approach is to require elevation before exposing local files to scripting _whatsoever_; this is of course why the OS requires Mozilla elevate privileges.

Comment: You've failed to explain why this is less secure than a file upload.

Comment: @SLC: A server-side PHP backend can't exploit security flaws to manipulate arbitrary files on my PC, because there's an internet in the way.

Comment: First of all, it **can** be done.  Are you ready to prove that negative?
If you don't believe, reference tiddly-wiki.
Second, is letting a user pick a file then shipping the contents back over the wire to the server that sent you the script in the first place (or any other server named by the first server) *more* secure?  That's exactly what <input type=file /> does.
Sec

Comment: @kovacsbv: Yes, it is, because it doesn't involve exposing the filesystem to a scripting engine, and to code that some arbitrary web developer wrote that executes on your local system. I concede that apparently HTML5 can perform this exposure, which is a shame.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit create a form, add file uploader, and in the onclick do `form.submit();` voila, your data is sent merely by selecting the file. I'd demonstrate using jsfiddle but it doesn't handle posting forms.

Comment: @SLC: At no stage has my argument even begun to claim that I am worried about data being sent. I'm talking about writing browsers and OSs in a _failsafe_ way to protect from security flaws.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: My point is that data getting sent over the wire is a lot more exposed but is much easier to write.  Failsafe is **not** one of the requirements listed above.  My purpose is not to start a tweedle beatle bottle puddle battle muddle over security.  I'm not writing DO-178B code here, and my organization is the one that will decide if the risks are acceptable in the environment we are using, not everybody on the internet who has no idea what I am doing.  I am asking for a solution that is simple and I can evaluate.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Notwithstanding, I would like to see a monolithic HTML/JAVASCRIPT file that reproduces one of these "blindingly obvious" security flaws in the scripting engine in any recent browser.

Comment: @kovacsbv: You don't appear to have understood me.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with executing or manipulating local files. Something needs access to read a file if it can be submitted, which browsers do support. There is perhaps a decent argument to be made for either side, it's not "blindingly obvious" that browsers should or have been designed to not allow this. Either they have been designed this way for this reason or not, you didn't provide any evidence in your answer to back up that they have been designed this way and for this reason.